# Could anyone explain about oom_badness() score in OOM killer?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

```
/*
 * If any of p's children has a different mm and is eligible for kill,
 * the one with the highest oom_badness() score is sacrificed for its
 * parent.  This attempts to lose the minimal amount of work done while
 * still freeing memory.
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments in [the source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L199) already do a good job at explaining it:

```
/**
 * oom_badness - heuristic function to determine which candidate task to kill
 * @p: task struct of which task we should calculate
 * @totalpages: total present RAM allowed for page allocation
 *
 * The heuristic for determining which task to kill is made to be as simple and
 * predictable as possible.  The goal is to return the highest value for the
 * task consuming the most memory to avoid subsequent oom failures.
 */
```

The `oom_badness()` function is indirectly called by [`out_of_memory()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L1045), which is the function responsible of handling a critical out of memory state.  When `out_of_memory()` is called (for example [by the page allocator](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L3851) or [by the page fault handler](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1077)), it iterates over all tasks to determine their "badness", and the task with the highest value gets forcibly killed (the actual chain of calls is [`select_bad_process()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L366) → [`oom_evaluate_task()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L310) → `oom_badness()`).

The "badness" of a task depends on multiple factors:

- How many pages are in its virtual memory.
- How many SWAP entries it owns.
- How much memory is the process using (total bytes / page size).
- If it was [already marked to be killed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/kernel/trace/ring_buffer.c#L1222) because it's responsible for the OOM, it gets the highest possible score.
- If it's the init process or a kernel thread, it is ignored.

In older kernel versions, the `oom_badness()` function used to be more complicated, for example taking into account different scaling factors and ["bonuses" for privileged processes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L180), but it was updated to make it "as simple and predictable as possible".

Comment: thx. but i had one question that: where it considers  virtual memory?   i read source code that score: `points = get_mm_rss(p->mm) + get_mm_counter(p->mm, MM_SWAPENTS) + mm_pgtables_bytes(p->mm) / PAGE_SIZE;` that means rss, swap and pagetable space used : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.2/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L233